# python catch web redirection

Tags: python, redirect, urllib, http-status-codes

my problem is about Web redirect ,, i'm using `urllib`>getcode() to know what status codes return

so here is my code

```
import urllib
a = urllib.urlopen("http://www.site.com/incorrect-tDirectory")
a.getcode()
```

`a.getcode()` return `200` but actually it's redirect to main page and i've check references that says redirect should return as i remember `300` or `301` but it's not `200` hopefully you got me 
so my question how to catch the redirection

Answer (score 1):

`urllib2.urlopen()` [doc page](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) says:

> This function returns a file-like object with two additional methods:

```
geturl() — return the URL of the resource retrieved, commonly used to determine if a redirect was followed
info() — return the meta-information of the page, such as headers, in the form of an mimetools.Message instance (see Quick Reference to HTTP Headers)
```

`urllib.urlopen()` actually implements `geturl()`, too, but it's not put as explicitly in the documentation.